# Database Design Help for Users, Roles, Teacher and Student in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I have a a user table that stores basic information. I have a roles table that has a Role name assigned. 
The roles and users are connected by many to many relationship called Assignment. So Assignment have User_ID and Role_ID. My users has many roles, admin, coordinators, students , teachers etc. One of my requirements is Teacher has many students. So one teacher have multiple students and many students have one teacher. How would i go about creating my database design? Should i create a separate Teacher table and Student Table and have many to many relationship? But that way roles table will be useless. I just want to know what is the best approach on rails that has One user table with roles. But the user role with teacher has many user role of students.

One additional thing is that all the other users has same information but the user with teachers need extra information. Now if i add those extra attributes in user table it will have many null values if it's not a teacher. How would i design the database in this case?

Comment: Students aren't normally assigned teachers. Instead, students typically enrol for subjects, which are taught by teachers (in classrooms). Is that model not appropriate here?

Comment: Just because you are using a role system does not mean that you should be shoehorning all the logic in your application into it. The two things can coexist and you should really be focusing on building a database model that reflects the actual domain like a @Strawberry suggested.

Comment: Its also silly to assume that one model will fit all. School systems vary a lot and while the model @Strawberry suggests is a pretty good fit for high schools, and higher education in most countries it may not fit basic education as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't change your roles implementation (though there's an excellent gem that provides roles and scoping that I would use https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify).

For the teacher and student relationship, if it is one-to-many, then you can

```
migration:
---

add_reference :users, :teacher, null: true, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }

model (user.rb):
---

belongs_to :teacher, class_name: 'User', required: false
has_many :students, foreign_key: 'teacher_id', class_name: 'User'

validate :valid_teacher_role

private

def valid_teacher_role
  errors.add(:teacher, 'should have the Teacher role') if teacher.present? && !teacher.has_role?(:teacher)
end
```

If it is many-to-many, then you can use a join table such as a `Class`, `Subject` or whatever makes sense in your use case.

For your second question, I will create a separate table for teacher specific fields, which will link back (belongs_to) to the user table.